# I want to know the most adj noun (or) the most adj

Tags: grammaticality

> The mountain scenery in East Java is the most exciting.

(OR)

> The mountain scenery in East Java is the most exciting one.

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: 'Scenery' is normally a non-count noun, and would be at best unidiomatic if not used as such here, so 'the most exciting one' is incorrect.

Comment: Either could be fine. To add to the first comment, there certainly *could* be a context where you are choosing between scenery (such as in a series of photographs), thereby using it as a count noun, and making the use of *one* reasonable. To say it's incorrect because it's unusual is an overstatement. Without context, it's *probably* wrong, but easily could be fine with the right context.